# Getting aggregated results with selected facet

Tags: elasticsearch

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm running into the current issue:

While being on the page, without any facet selected I run a query with some aggregations on my facets.

For example: on the "ladies shoes" page I run a query with "gender=ladies" and category "shoes" as filter, which gives me all the wanted results. Also there is an aggregation on "brand" which returns me all the brands. However, this also contains brands with a count of 0, since they don't match the "ladies shoes" criteria. But since no facet is selected, I can simply hide them, so the user won't see them.

So far, so good.

Now, when I run a query for "ladies shoes from Nike" (brand=nike as filter),  I get the same list of aggregations, but now all the brands have a count of 0, except Nike. Now, it's hard to just hide them, since we want to offer the possibility to filter on multiple (available) brands.

What should be the best approach to this, with as less queries as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're talking about multi select faceting as in your example - there is a very handy feature in the Elasticsearch - [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a
>   search request, after aggregations have already been calculated.

All you need to do, is to move your Nike brand filter to the `post_filter` of the query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
      ...
  },
  "aggs": {
      ...
  },
  "post_filter": { 
    "term": { "brand": "Nike" }
  }
}
```

which would allow you to calculate aggregations on all brands and only **after** it filter out selected brand.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that and this solves the problem partly.

For displaying the results I also use an aggregation, because the results are bundled by EAN in this case). Now the filter is not applied to these results (which I get).

So, I think a separate search-request (with according post_filters) is the only option here to get this right?

Comment: Most likely yes, could you share your request just in case?

Comment: Well, following the logic an extra query is unavoidable, and is not too bad, so I'll just stuck with that. It works like a charm now :-) Thanks!